# Angular element logs incorrect value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am doing a chat, using bootstrap and angular. Every message is displayed in its div with "well well-sm" classes. 
That's how the code responsible for that looks like:

```
<div ng-repeat="message in messages" class="media" >
     <h5 class="media-heading"><span>{{message.nick}}</span> {{message.time | date: "yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm"}}</h5>
     <div change-well-height class="well well-sm">{{message.body}}   
     </div>
</div>
```

But if its length is too big, we get this:
[How ordinary and long messages look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1GYn.png)

So I decided to add a directive *change-well-height* that looks if scrollWidth is bigger than clientWidth and changes height if so.
Code of the directive:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  app.directive('changeWellHeight', [
    '$location', function($location) {
      return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
          $( document ).ready(function(){
            console.log(element);
            console.log(element['0'].scrollHeight, element['0'].clientHeight, 'Height');
            console.log(element['0'].scrollWidth, element['0'].clientWidth, 'Width');
            if (element['0'].scrollHeight > element['0'].clientHeight || element['0'].scrollWidth > element['0'].clientWidth){
              //do stuff
            }
          });
        }
      };
    }
  ]);

}).call(this);
```

**NOW QUESTION** When I first look at the whole element logged out, I see, among a lot of properties both in Chrome and FF:
clientWidth: 467, 
scrollWidth: 2347

But next console.log shows:
435 435 "Width"

How is it possible that the same object gives me different values? I have no idea how to solve this

Comment: do you change the value at some point? console.log will not show all different values will just have the last one, in chrome at least , it is notable through a yellow triangle thing in the console next to the log.

Comment: @koox00, thanks for your comment. No yellow triangles there.
I don't change the value, just log it out. Could be it changes somewhere implicitely, but I didn't write any code to change that.
Also, it's strange. I log out all properties of the element and it's correct, and on the next line I log out only two properties - and one of them is not correct. I don't think it had time to get changed.

Comment: the text won't be rendered when `link` runs, try using `$timeout`

Comment: @charlietfl, yes, you are right. If you write the answer, I will vote for it. Or I can write it myself, if you want. So it's up to you.

God, I should've thought about this. Shame on me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `document.ready` which is of no value anyway, use `$timeout` so that the text will be rendered when your code runs:

```
app.directive('changeWellHeight', [
    '$location', '$timeout', function($location, $timeout) {
      return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
          $timeout(function(){
            console.log(element);
            console.log(element['0'].scrollHeight, element['0'].clientHeight, 'Height');
            console.log(element['0'].scrollWidth, element['0'].clientWidth, 'Width');
            if (element['0'].scrollHeight > element['0'].clientHeight || element['0'].scrollWidth > element['0'].clientWidth){
              //do stuff
            }
          });
        }
      };
    }
  ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this values are becoming updated before you open the properties inside the element at console. I already have noted this on Chrome, if you update some property value of an object before open its value at console, and then open the object, you'll see the value updated, even if you console this before the update.
To test, declare an array of array, console it, change the value, and then open the object, you'll see the value updated.

```
var array = [[0]];
console.log(array);
array[0][0] = 1;
```

Now, to figure out why the value are changing, we need more details.